# How to properly make a @media for hppi devices and & working with resize window

Tags: css, media-queries, device, dpi

I was trying some queries like "max/min width", "orientation portrait/landscape" "pixel ratio.." sharing in stack, which should work for mobile devices. Almost all, doesn't work with my HTC with hppi resolution and as a guest it doesn't work with other hppi devices. At last I found code like that:

```
@media only screen and (min-resolution: 117dpi) and (max-resolution: 119dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 131dpi) and (max-resolution: 133dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 145dpi) and (max-resolution: 154dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 162dpi) and (max-resolution: 164dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 169dpi) {}

@media only screen and (min-resolution: 165dpi) and (max-resolution: 168dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 155dpi) and (max-resolution: 160dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 134dpi) and (max-resolution: 144dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) and (max-resolution: 130dpi), only screen and (max-resolution: 116dpi) {}
```

This one works on all devices, but doesn't react when I scale the browser window.

How do I make my queries properly for all the states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're so specific with your CSS targeting, but,  [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/author/chriscoyier/) at CSS-tricks wrote a really good - slightly outdated - [reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for almost all devices.

```css
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- Galaxy S3 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- Galaxy S4 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- Galaxy S5 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}



/* ----------- HTC One ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}


/* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 1 and 2 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}


/* ----------- Galaxy Tab 10.1 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media 
  (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- Asus Nexus 7 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- Kindle Fire HD 7" ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- Kindle Fire HD 8.9" ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}


/* ----------- Non-Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
}

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
}


/* ----------- Apple Watch ----------- */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}


/* ----------- Moto 360 Watch ----------- */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```

For a more general approach I would use something the similar to the following [Pen](https://codepen.io/davidgilbertson/pen/aBpJzO) by [David Gilbertson](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-100-correct-way-to-do-css-breakpoints-88d6a5ba1862)

```css
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .phone-only {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  .tablet-portait-only {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .tablet-portrait-up {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .tablet-landscape-only {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .tablet-landscape-up {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1799px) {
  .desktop-only {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .desktop-up {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
  .big-desktop-up {
/* style goes here */ 
  }
}
```

and maybe combine that with [DPR media-queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)